# Are Video Game Back Stories On Topic?

Tags: discussion

Some video games incorporate complex stories and character development. Are questions about characters, worlds, stories, and fandom, that do not involve actual game play on topic?

I'm look, specifically, at this proposal ([Myst Lore](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25976/myst-lore)) and wondering if those types of questions would be welcomed here.

Comment: Also: [7 questions tagged 'plot'](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe they have every reason to be allowed. There is a wide wealth of canon to reference for answering them without devolving into discussion. Even some of the more subjective points can still be established by what canon is available, and concluding that the rest is up to interpretation *without* encouraging that interpretation to occur on-site.

Story is an important component of many games. It'd be very strange if we couldn't support it, in my opinion, as there exists a lot of objective Q&A possible for it.

Some examples we already have...

- [Who is the character you play in Portal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87/who-is-the-character-you-play-in-portal)
- [What are the connections between Portal series plot and Half-Life series plot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-are-the-connections-between-portal-plot-and-half-life-2-plot)
- [Where do those nasty red balls (eggs?) come from in Darwinia?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364/where-do-those-nasty-red-balls-eggs-come-from-in-darwinia)

Answer (score 6):

I vote they should be on-topic.

I don't see any particular problem with such questions. The people that are likely to raise them are gamers, the people most likely to be able to answer them are gamers, they are clearly about a specific game, I don't see any special opening for abuse...

Plus, we already have a few questions of this type - check out [story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) or [ending](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending) or [plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) - and I do not recall any complaints about them.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure we'll manage to find no consensus here as well, but I don't see the problem here. At the very worst, we'll end up with "good subjective" questions, where the "backstory" may need interpretation backed up by facts.

Answer (score 4):

**On Topic**

I don't have time to look up examples, but we have fielded these questions before without any problem, or even noticing a difference. I haven't seen anyone comment to the negative, so I'd say that's already community acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, the backstory is so tied up with the gameplay they are on topic *simpliciter*. A good example of this is World of Warcraft, where the story dictates what quests are available.

Example questions:

- [Has the Cataclysm changed Northrend?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11841/has-the-cataclysm-changed-northrend)
- [Lich King raids are still available or disabled?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12505/lich-king-raids-are-still-available-or-disabled)