# Should I ask lore/physical world questions about a universe on scifi.stack... or gaming.stack

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

For questions that relate to lore or the mechanics in an imaginary world what is described in both a game and in other material (e.g. books), is it better to ask the question here at gaming.stackexchange.com or at scifi.stackexchange.com?

**Example Question:** Within the Warcraft universe, what precisely is the state of being undead? How is it different to being alive? *(The Warcraft universe is described in the World of Warcraft game, the Warcraft series of games, but also in books and comics.)*

Comment: Sites _can_ overlap. It's okay.

Comment: by extension, would posting the same question on two sites be acceptable?

Comment: @chobok Please don't cross-post questions. While there's some overlap in topical scope, SciFi.SE and Gaming.SE are two completely different sites with different audiences: ask the site you think has the experts needed to answer the question and tailor it specifically for that site. For example, asking about out-of-game lore is, as badp mentioned, off-topic here: if you're interested in that as your example question suggests, you want to ask on SciFi.

Answer (score 3):

Just because a question is on-topic for Scifi it doesn't mean it's off-topic for Gaming, or viceversa.

You can see our policy about lore [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/game-canon-questions-which-extend-beyond-the-context-of-the-story-and-its-materi), just be aware **the question has to be about an actual videogame.** Questions about a Starcraft book would be off-topic here, but a lore question about Starcraft that finds an answer in a Starcraft book would be fine.

Comment: I agree, although if you're looking for a specific in-game reason (or mechanic) you're probably better off asking here as SciFi.SE will likely delve into speculation and general lore about undead. Of course, if you *want* that level of speculation, you're much better off on SciFi.