# Do we allow World of Warcraft lore questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I was wondering about the little domed model in the following screenshot—where is this and how can I get there—where might I ask such a question?  I don't think [this discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4542/should-i-ask-lore-physical-world-questions-about-a-universe-on-scifi-stack-or) applies to my question, but it has a parallel.

[image]

Is it the Blood Elf starting zone? The Isle of Quel'Danas?  Something else?

Comment: As an aside, I believe that is Sunwell Plateau, a Burning Crusade raid instance.

Comment: is it not central shattrath? That "lamp" at the top of the picture is actually a Naaru.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I thought he was referring to the city in the dome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are on topic but you should be careful how you word them.

There are people who disagree with it be on topic, so expect some down votes.

Answer (score 15):

Lore Questions are on-topic on Arqade, so there's nothing wrong with asking this question on the site. [Feel free to do so.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)