# I have modified this question is this now okay?

Tags: support, closing

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114659/whats-the-official-in-game-explanation-if-any-on-why-we-get-town-portal-when

Before I asked why we get town portal when defeating skeleton king. What I mean is if there is an official folklore explanation why.

So that's not an why the designer design game this way.

As far as I know there is none. However, I wonder if I miss anything.

If the question is unsalvageable, can anyone please tell me why.

Comment: I think the question might have been fine even in its original wording.

Comment: And yet I got 7 downvotes with very little explanation.

Comment: I got downvotes and close votes.

Comment: And why it's stupid?

Comment: He probably thinks it's stupid because you could just as easily ask "Is there an official folklore explanation for why monsters drop health and mana globes, or magic items they clearly weren't using? Where did that rat carry that halberd, anyway?" Some things are pretty obviously gameplay features. Regardless of whether or not the question is closeworthy, to some people at least, the answer is fairly obvious that it's a simple gameplay mechanic that's not tied to the story. Thus, downvotes.

Comment: @Sterno the rat carried the halberd to fight the demons, *duh*

Comment: @Sterno Looks like your comment could have been the final answer for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that it is *clearly* not a "why did they design it this way" question. I personally think the question was okay-ish in both its original form and its new form, but you might be interested in this related meta-discussion:

[Game canon questions which extend beyond the context of the story and its material](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/game-canon-questions-which-extend-beyond-the-context-of-the-story-and-its-materi)

Answer (score -4):

At first blush, it really did sound like a, "Why did the devs design it this way" type of question, in my opinion.

That said, it may not have been, but either way, even if it's a lore question, it still should not be reopened.  There's nothing in the story at all that addresses this at all.  Not that that's a stretch, as there are plot holes all over the place in Diablo 3.

If it *was* addressed, I'd say re-open it.  But since it's just, "Oh, quest completed!  Here's Town Portal, now use it!", there's nothing to address.  It's asking for details that don't exist.

Comment: So... it should remain closed because the answer is "there is no official in-game explanation"? Do all questions need to have a positive answers? I don't think so. As I see it, it's like asking how to do something in a game and the answer is that you can't, except instead of asking about a feature, it's asking about the story.

Comment: That's my point. If there is no in game explanation then no is an answer. For example, the blacksmith's apprentice died. There is an in game explanation there. Namely the player may stumble upon it's corpses.

Comment: Okay there is no in game explanation. Does everybody knows that there is no in game explanation? Is it obvious?

Comment: Take a look at the link Oak posted.  We allow lore questions, but there are limits, as long as it *is* addressed in the lore.  Since it's not, what use does a question have that's only answer is, "No, it's not addressed" have?

Comment: @JimThio IMO, there needs to be an in-game reason you're asking.  If the game was hinting as some sort of reason or rationale, or it did explain but you didn't understand or missed something, that would be perfectly valid to ask about.  But assuming there's a reason and asking on that basis is not.  You could ask literally the same question about every aspect of every game; it would be a colossal waste of space.  Asking based on curiosity is allowed but, again, I think there should be some reason behind said curiosity beyond "I thought this up at random".

Comment: Speaking from a lot of experience trying to define the scope of another site (cooking) over the years, it's *really* important to try to define the allowed scope of questions in terms of the questions themselves, not the answers. It's generally awful if you have to know the answer (or lack of answer) in order to decide whether it's on-topic - the OP is asking the question because they don't know the answer, so they won't have any way to know whether their question is okay, and it ends up being hard to fairly enforce, and worse, feeling arbitrary and unfair to the OP.

Comment: @Jefromi Lore questions reside in a strange area; people ask about story points, and clarifying them might help them understand the plot better.  Personally, I'm not a fan of any lore questions at all, but the community think we keep them, so we keep them.  Problem is, where can you draw the line?  Our line is essentially, "If you're playing poke the plot hole, it gets closed."  As Matthew said, without that, you can ask questions about each and every little point, and the utility of such are extremely low.  It's not perfect, but that's what we've hashed out.

Comment: @fbueckert I understand that you're trying to draw a line. My point, however, is that you should draw it based on the questions themselves ("this sort of lore question is on/off-topic"), rather than based on the answer ("this lore question does not have a canonical explanation and is therefore off-topic"). It makes the rules much friendlier and easier to enforce.

Comment: @Jefromi It *is* based on the question.  We're talking the same thing here, and your example for basing it on the answer is actually basing it off of the question.  It just requires expertise to be able to determine if that particular item was addressed in the lore or not.

Comment: For example, if I ask why the blacksmith apprentice died (and don't respawn like the rest) there is indeed an answers that most players miss. Would that have been a legitimate question?